# How can I invert this matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra

How can I prove that the inverse of following matrix:

$\Omega_{ij} = \omega \delta_{ij} +i \varepsilon_{ijk} v_k$

is, in fact

$\Omega_{ij}^{-1} = \dfrac{\omega}{\omega^2-\vec{v}^2} \delta_{ij} -\dfrac{i}{\omega^2-\vec{v}^2} \varepsilon_{ijk} v_k -\dfrac{1}{\omega(\omega^2-\vec{v}^2)}v_iv_j $

?????

Comment: If you have a suggested form of the inverse matrix, you could always multiply it with the matrix itself and see if the product is equal to the identity matrix. I am a bit puzzled about your statement, though, because $\Omega^{-1}$ has some parameter $\omega$ which the initial matrix $\Omega$ lacks.

Comment: Your term $i \varepsilon_{ijk} v_k$ needs to be clarified.  Is the first $i$ the complex square root of $-1$ or the index value as in the subscripts ?

Comment: the $i$ is $i=\sqrt{-1}$...

Comment: @StephenG If that $i$ were an index value, the right side would not be a tensor because it would not transform correctly under rotations.

Comment: @G.Smith All it says is "linear algebra".  While it might be assumed to tensors, it could easily have just been typos.  We get typo ridden equations all the time, alas.   I prefer some clarifications in these cases - stating the source or context of equations really is useful.  Or maybe I'm just in a nit-picky mood. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix $\Omega^{-1}_{jk}$ exists, it seems plausible that it is of the form
$$
\Omega^{-1}_{jk} = A \delta_{jk} + B \epsilon_{jkl} v_l + C v_jv_k 
$$
for some values of $A$, $B$, and $C$.  We also know that we must have $\Omega_{ij} \Omega^{-1}_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$.

Take it from there.

Comment: How do you know that the inverse has this form?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMelo What additional terms would you propose?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMelo:  The short answer is that you don't;  if you guess an ansatz and it leads you to a contradiction, that means you guessed the wrong ansatz.  More generally, as a rule, the inverse of a matrix written in a coordinate-free form has to be "built out of" the same things the matrix itself is built out of.  The only three rank-2 tensors you can construct out of $\delta$, $\epsilon$, and $v$ are those three, and so if the inverse can be written in terms of them, it must be a linear combination of those three terms.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, perfect! But I was thinking in considerate the following: $\Omega^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\omega I_d +A}$ and take the sries expansion consideranting tha $I_d= \delta_{ij}$ and $A= i\varepsilon_{ijk} v_k$. This form I could show you ansatz...

Comment: @JoãoPauloMelo:  Formally speaking, that would be correct.  There would be an infinite number of terms in such a series, though, in increasing powers of $v$. You'd have to "resum" all of these terms to get them into the form you have in your question.  For example, the terms proportional to $\delta_{ij}$ would presumably end up being $$\omega^{-1} \delta_{ij} \left( 1 + \frac{v^2}{\omega^2} + \frac{v^4}{\omega^4} + \dots \right)$$which would then be equivalent to $\omega \delta_{ij}/(\omega^2 - v^2)$.